# Adding a position-delimited .txt file into javascript script of an html document for parsing

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, csv

The .txt file is in a working directory on my desktop.

I want to read this file into a variable and then parse through the lines of it to extract the elements at each position. Then I want to save each element of each line of the file as part of an element in an array.

Pseudocode would be something like this.

```
var text = ["file.txt"];

for (line in text){

    String first = line.substring(…);
    String second = line.substring(…);
    String third = line.substring(…);
    String fourth = line.substring(…);
    array.push([first, second, third, fourth]);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want some free work. You don't have a specific question, and what you want isn't totally clear. Reading local files with JavaScript is relatively new. If you just search about each part of this then all the info should be there for you to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know. I wanted to see if there was an easy way to do this that I just didn't know about. When I find out how to do this, I'll post back here.